# Convert row data into column data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables. Marks and Subjects.

Marks Table

[image]

Subject Table

[image]

I have written this SQL query:

[image]

I want output like the following:

[image]

Comment: SO is not a SW-for-free service. Start by doing some attempts of your own and, if no luck, post what you have tried so that people can comment and, hopefully, help you.

Comment: i have tried.. i tried to implement pivot table but same issue was there. so that's why i posted here

Comment: Please don't attach images (only). Provide the structure of the (relevant) tables as `CREATE TABLE` and sample data as `INSERT INTO` statements. Also include the query and the desired output as **text**.

Comment: [how to post a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read and follow community netiquette before posting

Comment: @ArnavThakur, please post the query that you wrote and the results.  You said "same issue was there", but I don't see where you've described what "issue" you've encountered.

Comment: [Forum Etiquette: How to post data for a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/).

Answer (score 0):

This is psuedo-sql, as the OP has posted images, and I'm not going to write out DDL for it. Anyway, this should be enough to get you started (however, is untested).

```
SELECT Title,
       MAX(CASE WHEN ExamType = 1 THEN Mark ELSE 0 END) AS Mark1
       MAX(CASE WHEN ExamType = 2 THEN Mark ELSE 0 END) AS Mark2
FROM YourTable
GROUP BY Title;
```

I'll be happy, however, to change this to something that works for your environment if you get rid of the images and post DDL and `INSERT` statements.